# GetDate() is returning the same time at various points in a procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but when I do something like in a SQL Server 2008 SSMS session like:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

set @start = GetDate()

Update blah blah...a huge amount of rows...;

set @end = GetDate()
```

When I try to do a `datediff` of seconds between `@start` and `@end`, I get zero.

So I printed `@start` and `@end` and they are identical. The query took several minutes. What is going on here?

EDIT--the problem was that the Set @start and Set @end were inside a cursor Open/close block (but not inside the fetch loop) and apparently MS treats those as the exact same time.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: What does the part of the procedure where you compare start and end look like?

Comment: also add the print code. For example if you use `raiserror nowait` to echo the print immediately things might become clearer.

Comment: I'm simply printing at the end of the procedure, formatting them with the 108 format code (just the time portion).    The nowait should be moot--I don't care *when* it's printed, I've captured the "current" time in the variables so nothing should be changing the value of those variables.  I'm not at my work machine now so I can't get the exact code, but I'm just thinking I missed some cardinal rule somewhere.

Comment: I am thinking that you might be printing the same date twice and doing a datediff of same date and not using both the dates you have declared.

Comment: I believe standard SQL requires it to appear as though the procedure executes instantaneously, so the current time is frozen while the procedure executes.  Certainly, some DBMS interpret the rules that way, even if there's a SLEEP 60 in the procedure.

Comment: @jonathanLeffler. That is my fear--somewhere in the back of my mind that rings a bell. If it's the case it's insanity (in my opinion). I'm simply trying to benchmark here.  But isuppose one was using multiple update or insert statements and wanted, say, to fill a date time field will the exact time relative to when the other dml occurred, it would look as if they all executed at once.

Comment: I believe I've found the issue.  I was benchmarking, and was testing an update statement done in a cursor loop.  The start variable was set after the Open and the end var was set just before cursor close.  They were both outside the While loop--but apparently sql-server sees everything within a cursor's Open & Close statements as exactly the same time, even if the cursor is looping for a half an hour and each update statement takes several seconds--the GetDate() calls that are completely outside those statements and that loop are all the exact same time.   Just senseless.

Answer (score 0):

Four your specific use case you may find that Datetime2 and SYSDATETIME() will give you more precision .  You can then use the nanoseconds datediff operator.

*As an aside you should assume that UPDATE myDate = GETDATE() WHERE "lots of records"   and UPDATE myDatefield = SYSDATETIME() during an update process are always going to give you different date values than you expect depending on the phase of the moon and the score of the last Chicago Bears game.*

This is because GETDATE() is not deterministic at two different level in the bowels of SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen after system suspend/resume.
It recovers after sql service is restarted.